# How can I switch to Space 1 with the mouse?

Tags: mouse, space

What can I do to be able to switch to space 1 easily with my mouse only ? I touch about an Exposé corner but there is a limited list of actions possible... I though about the 3rd mouse button but there is no space command in there...

Any idea ? Any trick ?

EDIT : I see that on the 3rd button mouse, there is a "Other..." item in the popup action list. Choosing this opens a dialog where I have to choose an applescrit (as far as I know). Is it possible to make a script that switch to Space 1.

PS : I really want to shift to space one in 1-move or 1-click. I know how to go to Space 1 using only the mouse, But not "at once".

Comment: I've not used this, but the question interested me and I came across something called steermouse, which you can use to assign key presses to the various buttons on your mouse - so depending what mouse you have, it might be a solution for you. http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/

Comment: Have you looked into BetterTouchTool? This might support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722) can definitely do it via keyboard shortcuts.

After you install BTT, switch to Normal Mouse tab. There you click on `+ Add new mouse button` and then click 3rd button inside the `Click here to select mouse button`.

Next, if you already haven't set up keyboard shortcuts to switch directly to a space, just pick any of the three modifier keys (CTRL, Option, Command), click inside the `Custom Keyboard Shortcut` field and press the key along with number 1, e.g `Ctrl-1`.

[image: BTT mouse button setup]

**Note:** if you have already set up such a shortcut, you have to disable it before trying to enter the shortcut to BTT, because OS X would otherwise capture this event and BTT won't get it.

Now close BTT window and go to `System Preferences` > `Exposé & Spaces` > `Spaces` and select the appropriate modifier from the `To switch directly to a space:` list:

[image: Spaces configuration]

Now you should be able to switch to Space 1 directly with Middle click.

PS. I should mention that I have Magic Mouse and have BTT set up with three-finger gestures to switch spaces from mouse - very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You could enable the icon for the menu bar in the System Preferences -> Expose & Spaces -> Spaces -> Show spaces in the menu bar

or

Define the 3rd mouse button "To activate Spaces" on the right side at the same System Preference

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to use only the  mouse and to be able to switch in 1 click or 1 move.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean like flinging the mouse towards the space? I don't think you can do it other than by dragging something there - you could grab an icon from the desktop or a random window and fling it in the right direction - it'll pause briefly at the edge before moving into the space. If you use an icon from the desktop, they are common between all spaces, so it won't go amiss.

Other than that I don't think there's a way - of course Lion will bring some gestures that work with the trackpad or the magic mouse, but I don't think it's what your really want.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in how you propose to use the mouse to instantly switch to another Space. The only thing I can think of would be some kind of gesture, unless you are willing to sacrifice e.g. the right mouse button to enable this.

If you want to use gestures, perhaps you should give [FlyGesture](http://flyingmeat.com/flygesture/) a try. It's free too. Using FlyGesture, you can have a gesture execute the keyboard shortcut needed to switch to the next Space, or even a specific Space.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mentioned methods above, you can drag a window to an edge or corner of the screen and that'll make spaces switch to the space in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this pref pane that does just that. I have a mouse with lateral buttons that I can now switch spaces

https://mousefix.org/

PD: is free and open source (i think)